# How can I restart Compiz from a TTY? (& Related, how can I set up a fallback WM?)

Tags: command-line, 11.04, compiz, tty

I'm testing Natty, and Compiz keeps crashing on me. However, it doesn't always give me the option to restart Compiz, and for some reason doesn't have a fallback window manager(WM) configured.

Without a WM, all my programs are still running, but they're not accepting input from the keyboard, and I can't switch between them.

I can, however, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and get a terminal, and I can `killall Xorg` to reset everything; but, I'd rather just reset Compiz, if possible.

If I try typing `compiz --replace` in the TTY, it complains "fatal--couldn't open display." Is there a way to have TTY1 restart Compiz? Like `compiz --replace --display=something`?

Additionally, is there a way to configure a fallback window manager so that there's an easier way to recover from Compiz crashing?

Comment: You should start accepting answers.  So far you've asked 8 questions but haven't accepted any answers.

Comment: can this be simplified for a (terminal) newb?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Switch to terminal number 1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace
```

Sometimes it doesn't restart. Just kill all `compiz` processes and try again in case.

Comment: Latest unity starts itself on DISPLAY=:0 automatically.

Comment: You can also switch use 'setsid unity' btw

Comment: Both your comments seem valuable, but they're not yet clear to me: do they mean **1)** that **DISPLAY=:0** can be dropped, even when using **tty**-1 to replace **unity** running, crashedly, in tty-7 **?** and **2)** do you recommend using **setsid** for this purpose (rather than () or & disown or nohup) and if so why **?**

Comment: cf **[setsid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man2/setsid.2.html)** and http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal/106359#106359

Comment: I have killed compiz and I had to run `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace ` to start unity. Just running compiz did not show full screen window decoration and did not automatically start unity.

Comment: This closed almost all of my 1000+ windows I had open.  Seems to be even more destructive than logout/logon (which tries to reopen closed windows).

Answer (score 13):

You need to set the DISPLAY environment variable, in the usual case of a single Xorg instance you can do that with

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my menubars and taskbar having disappeared.

I tried the above solution but it did not work. However with the following I got my stuff back to normal :)

```
DISPLAY=:0
compiz --replace
```