# How do I port a FreeBSD daemon to Ubuntu?

Tags: services

I had a FreeBSD machine and it had a `/usr/sbin/daemon` command which could run my program in the background.

The question is how to do something similar in Ubuntu? I would like something I can put in a startup script.
What I mean is my program can't put itself in a background when starts.

I tried:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
```

But it just starts the program and I must wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `--background` option of `start-stop-daemon`. From the manual page of [start-stop-daemon(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/start-stop-daemon.8):

> -b, --background
>   Typically  used  with  programs  that  don't  detach on their own.
>   This option will force start-stop-daemon to fork before starting the
>   process, and force it into the background.  WARNING: start-stop-daemon
>   cannot check the exit status if the process fails to execute for
>   any  reason.  This  is  a last resort, and is only meant for programs
>   that either make no sense forking on their own, or where it's not
>   feasible to add the code for them to do this themselves.

In a shell, programs can be backgrounded with `&` as in:

```
$ myprogram &
[1] 5042
```

Comment: how do I run a command with the arguments with & ? I tried "my_command args" & but it didn't work, although my_command args by itself worked well.

Comment: @Alex `my_command args &` works too. The `jobs` builtin will show you the program with the *Running* label. What makes you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: @Lekensteyn, yes, you're right.

Comment: the 'nohup' program was designed for exactly this and has been around since the inception of unix. has no one heard of it lol?

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to run something and detach it (so it runs in the background) there are [half a dozen methods that I evaluated yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/a/106359/449). The easiest is just to wrap the command in parenthesis:

```
(command)
```

You can close the terminal and move on with life and the application will keep running. There's obviously no control over the process now short of looking it up and nuking it (`kill`, `killall`, etc), or it quitting itself.

If you need something a bit more elegant, I'd look at upstart scripts. Upstart is the replacement for the System V init system (ie the files in `/etc/init.d/`). To give you an idea of how an Upstart script looks, you can see the existing Upstart jobs in `/etc/init/`.

There's a lovely cookbook of examples on the Upstart website:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/