# setting PATH to /etc/profile or /etc/environment does not work with sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables, intellij

I want to launch Intellij IDEA IDE via `sudo idea.sh`. `sudo` because IDE needs to manupulate files from `/etc/share`. `idea.sh` is placed at `/home/<username>/<path>/bin/idea.sh`.

I tried to add this path to `PATH` environment variable by adding `export PATH="$PATH":<path-to-idea>/bin` to `/etc/profile` or by changing string in `/etc/environment` from `PATH="blahblah"` to `PATH="<path-to-idea>/bin:blahblah"`. In both cases after `sudo echo $PATH` command I got string with my path to IDEA added.

But when I tried to execute idea.sh via `sudo idea.sh` I got `sudo: idea.sh: command not found`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `sudo -E idea.sh` to preserve your environment. You may get an error.

Comment: the same result

Comment: `sudo -i idea.sh`  will do

Comment: `-bash: idea.sh: command not found`

Comment: Easier to place the script in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Do you mean to place idea.sh in `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 2):

Just to run:

> sudo ./idea.sh

in [background](https://askubuntu.com/a/106897/181228):

> sudo ./idea.sh &

Also visit similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015495/2650174).

Comment: `sudo: ./idea.sh: command not found`.