# setsid by default in Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, session

So I've just discovered the command `setsid`, which makes life a whole lot easier for running programs from Terminal. What I'd like to know is if there's a way to set programs to launch in a new session automatically, because honestly I'm probably going to be prepending `setsid` before everything I run now. Is this bad practice for some reason?

Comment: You could try something like this `alias foo='setsid foo'` and add this to your .bashrc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't seem to do anything. Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from creating aliases for your programs, it's not really possible to have `setsid` automatically prefixed before *every* command typed in the terminal. However, I find it is very useful to create an `.inputrc` in your home folder and place in it (observing the quoting):

```
Control-o: "setsid "
```

You can now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in the terminal and then type your command; it saves a lot of time if you need to keep repeating it. There is no error in the placement of quotes: it allows you to immediately type a command after the shortcut is used. This functionality and much more is provided by bash's `readline` library: see `man bash` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html).

With reference to your second question, it isn't bad practice to use `setsid` a lot and just depends on your particular needs. In fact it is extremely useful, because, as noted [at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsid.2.html),

> setsid creates a new session if the calling process is not a process group
>          leader.  The calling process is the leader of the new session, the process
>          group leader of the new process group, and has no controlling tty...The calling process will be the only process in this new
>          process group and in this new session.

Hence the program launched with `setsid` has complete independence from the terminal from which it was started, as a new process has been forked.

There are also other similar, but different ways of detaching a program from the terminal such as `nohup` or `disown`. (It should be said that `setsid` is a program from the `util-linux` package, while `disown` is a bash builtin.)  This question may be of great interest, as it touches upon such related topics:

- [Running programs in the background from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal)