# Opening an Application via Terminal

Tags: command-line

I am a new user of precise pangolin and learning to use the terminal. I just wonder whether there is any easy command/combination of commands to open an application (LibreOffice Writer, for example) via terminal, just like we use `sudo apt-get install <<packagename>>` to install an application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just type the the name of the application you want to start. In your case it would be `libreoffice` or if you want to go to writer directly you can type `libreoffice --writer`

Comment: Alternatively, you can also run it directly with [something like `/opt/libreoffice4.4/program/soffice` as seen here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352923/318461)

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want the application tied to a controlling terminal you can type the application name followed by `& disown`.

In [@Germar's example](https://askubuntu.com/a/173246/830570) the full command would read `libreoffice & disown`.  This would enable you to close the terminal you launched from, and continue using libreoffice.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You can close the terminal if only using ``&`` (at least on my 12.04). To see about ``&``, ``disown`` and ``nohup``, check http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886. See also http://askubuntu.com/q/264257/58950 and http://askubuntu.com/q/106351/58950.