# How to open an application in terminal and detach it?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I opened Cairo-dock in my terminal with: `open cairo-dock` and that worked but if I close the terminal it goes with it. How can I keep it open regardless of the terminal?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP (hangup) signal is by convention the way a terminal warns depending processes of logout.
>   Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.
>   nohup is a low-level utility simply configuring a command to ignore a signal. As seen below, nohup is very far from being a full-featured batch system solving all the problems of running programs asynchronously.

See manual:

```
man nohup
```

Example:

```
nohup cairo-dock &
```

Answer (score 19):

Yet another way: [`disown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_%28Unix%29)

> In the bash shell, the disown builtin command is used to remove jobs from the job table, or to mark jobs so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to them if the parent shell receives it (e.g. if the user logs out).

For example:

```
cairo-dock & disown
```

Comment: disown is a bash specific, so I would not recommend using it, if you want it to work in other POSIX shells.

Comment: I like this one much more than nohup tbh

Answer (score 7):

I personally use screen for this kind of stuff.

```
screen -d -m -S cairo_session open cairo-dock
```

What's good about this is that if you want to terminate cairo-dock, you can reconnect to the screen session and terminate it.

```
screen -S cairo_session -X quit
```

[Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) has other uses. It's a terminal multiplexer.

Comment: I would however recommend using tmux instead of screen.  It has the same functionality (different binding though Ctrl-b instead of Ctrl-a), but works better than screen (at least for me).