# How to close terminal after opening something from it

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I am a linux newbie so this maybe a very stupid question, I will try to ask my question by giving an example.
When I execute command in terminal

> chromium-browser

chromium opens up but I cannot close the terminal without closing the browser. when I quit the terminal browser closes automatically So I wanted  know how to close that terminal without closing the browser.

Comment: Related: [Running programs in the background from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal) and [How to open an application in terminal and detach it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264257/how-to-open-an-application-in-terminal-and-detach-it)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by running something like this from the terminal:

```
chromium-browser &
disown
```

You need to `disown` the program from the terminal.

More information about `disown`:

```
~$ disown --help
disown: disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid ...]
    Remove jobs from current shell.
    
    Removes each JOBSPEC argument from the table of active jobs.  Without
    any JOBSPECs, the shell uses its notion of the current job.
    
    Options:
      -a    remove all jobs if JOBSPEC is not supplied
      -h    mark each JOBSPEC so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the
            shell receives a SIGHUP
      -r    remove only running jobs
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option or JOBSPEC is given.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to disassociate the browser from the terminal. I think this is the sequence:

```bsh
chromium-browser </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
# or
nohup chromium-browser &

disown
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Place an `&` after any command you want to run in background after the terminal exits.

```
chromium-browser &
```

should do the trick.
[Reference to StackOverflow question explaining it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean)