# Move running program to background in bash

Tags: bash

If I'm running a program in bash, I can suspend it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. If I want to leave the program running, I can then use the `bg` command. Is there some way to directly put the program in the background, without having to type `bg`?

**Clarification**: I want to put the program in the background when it is already running, without suspending it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I don't want to keep a program running when the terminal window is closed, and I can't type a different command. I want to put a process in the background when it is already running.

Comment: yes this is not a duplicate, please reopen this.

Comment: Thanks for all those guys who helped in reopening this.. @Kalle, The question is now reopened.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As to actually finding an answer for the question, I guess the only way is to suspend it first and then background it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to move a running program to background(while the process is still in running state).
However there is an application called [GNU-Screen](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/screen),using which you can run any number of console-based applications--interactive command shells, curses-based applications, text editors, etc.--within a single terminal.
Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935) on GNU-Screen.
Note that it does not do exactly what you asked,but serves the purpose anyway.
Example:
Here is the implementation of what you asked using GNU-Screen.

1. Run `screen`
   You will get details about the software.Press return.
2. Now,you will see your normal terminal.However it is a window of screen.Type any command say `vlc`. It will start the process within that window.
3. Now to open a new window type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd>.You can run a new command here.Note that the process which you started in window 1 is still running.
4. To detach from screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd>.You now return back to your old termianl.However any process that you started from screen would still be running.

Answer (score 4):

To my best of knowledge you could run it and then append an **&** after it like this: `myprogram &`

I may be very wrong here however.

**[EDIT]:** Taking a closer look to this, if you run the above, *the application will close when you close the terminal.* If you would like the application to run in the background, then, as far as I know, *the application needs to be written in such a way that supports daemon behavior.*

**[EDIT 2]:** `nohup command &` appears to be closer to what you want to achieve. Nohup will allow an application to run, and will both ignore its input and redirect its output to a file called `nohup.out` in the current directory.

Comment: I don't really care if it's closed when I close the terminal window. All I'm looking for is a keyboard shortcut in bash that works like Ctrl+Z but will keep the process running in the background, instead of suspending it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not a real answer. I wonder what the different of Bash between Ubuntu with MSYS.

I running MSYS and when i run `Application/Chrome &`, it immediately go to background process. I can use the MSYS bash as next prompt start blinking.

And are this questions [Move running program to background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal) with similar intents?