# KDE Desktop icons glitched after suspend (Kubuntu 16.10)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, suspend, kde

I have a system76 laptop (Oryxp3) which works flawlessly with Kubuntu, hibernation and suspension too, drivers and everything too (battery sucks, but it's mostly a software problem which will take a lot of time to address), but for whatever reason only the DESKTOP makes some weird glitches when resuming from suspension/hibernation.

I can fix it by changing Layout from "Folder view" to "Desktop", applying and then reverting back to "Folder view", so it seems like a refresh problem.

Although I would love to have either a proper fix to refresh my desktop after suspend, or a command to do that. A hack or a workaround that I can bind to a command, I'm just too lazy to unlock widgets, right click, change option, apply, revert, apply every restore from suspension.

My GPU is NVIDIA GTX 1070 with NVIDIA drivers: 375.39

Here is how it looks, although sometimes is worse and the font gets all colored in weird ways and it's unreadable:

[image: Desktop icons with graphic glitches]

Answer (score 2):

Nvidia cards exhibit this weird display corruption when resuming from sleep. Simplest work around is toggle the compositor: alt+shft+f12

Comment: This doesn't work on my system, only thing that gets rid of it is:killall plasmashell; kstart plasmashell

Comment: A similar issue is still a present issue with Kubuntu 18.04.2 x64 on NVIDIA driver 430.26. A discussion into the bug is discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6yfmo7/weird_graphical_glitches_on_suspend/).

Comment: @AdrianMaire I don't think I was able to answer because it was already closed as a duplicate, but I later posted a response to this question on the unix forum instead https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378177/17168 The bug is fixed in up to date kde/nvidia drivers, but it's still sometimes useful to restart plasma: current one-liner command is: kstart5 plasmashell -- --replace

Comment: @Ozone, I requested to re-open, and it seems done. You might want to add you solution. Also, you can link the unix page for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed, see closed reports (from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378177/17168):

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344326
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56610
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382115

I haven't had the problem with glitched desktop icons for over a year or two now but I do still notice some apps with accelerated contexts will be glitched after a restart but it can usually be fixed by just moving the window or refreshing a page.

If you are running an older KDE version or you just want to restart plasma for another reason you can use (Sources: [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/481738/31861) and [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5d2ly/how_do_you_properly_restart_kwin_and_plasmashell/ebmc2x5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) ):

KDE > 5.13

```
 kstart5 plasmashell -- --replace
```

KDE > 5.10

```
 kquitapp5 plasmashell
 kstart5 plasmashell
```

KDE 5

```
 killall plasmashell
 kstart plasmashell
```

KDE 4

```
killall plasma-desktop
kstart plasma-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by adding:

```
[QtQuickRendererSettings] 
GraphicsResetNotifications=true
```

to ~/.config/plasmashellrc