# KDE Plasma copy & paste stopped working, which service, how to restart

Tags: kde

Sometimes after a long usage (several days) of KDE Plasma, copy & paste suddenly stops working. (Specifically, paste command always pastes whatever I had last in the buffer, but I'm not able to copy anything new into the buffer.)

(At the same time, moving windows around also stopped working. Maybe related: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out). Using `kwin --replace` fixes that, i.e. now I can again move windows around. However, copy & paste is still broken in the same way.)

Which service is responsible for the copy & paste handling? Is it possible to restart just that service, so that I don't need to restart the whole system and log out/in again?

(This is Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE 5.)

I found `klipper` now, and tried `kstart klipper`, but that does not help (after some iterations of `kwin --replace`, `killall plasmashell`, `plasmashell`, even the paste clipboard stopped working, and `klipper` brought back the paste, which still had the old frozen buffer content, but it still does not let me copy anything new to the clipboard buffer).

I also found `ksmserver` but not sure yet what it does. Also not sure yet how to properly restart that.

I also found `dbus-daemon`, which might be related. Not sure yet. Also not sure yet  how to properly restart that. `killall dbus-daemon` did a full logout of the session.

Comment: I had the ghost/empty entry stuck at top of stack issue and tracked it to kdeconnect trying to "Share the clipboard between devices". Unticked, and ghost entry disappeared.

Comment: @CNSKnight I think that's worth pasting as an actual answer, as it's almost certainly my problem too. The accepted answer is still perfectly valid, and should work whatever the cause, but if you don't _need_ to share the clipboard, your solution should prevent it happening again.

Comment: I found that x2go was messing with the clipboard. Once I closed it clipboard start working again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that going into system tray settings then disabling clipboard in 'Extra items', applying the change and then enabling it again results in a 'Restart' of the clipboard service.