# KDE panel rendering issues

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I'm not sure what triggers this bug yet. When it occurs, the bottom panel has odd behavior. If I close a window, it keeps drawing the entry as if it were still open. However, the "hitbox" for the mouse for each application acts as if it were not open. Basically, it acts like it has stopped rendering the changes to what applications are open. Let me clarify in an example.

Currently I am experiencing this bug. I have open firefox, telegram, remmina, thunderbird, a remmina session, and konsole. I closed telegram, konsole, and thunderbird , however the entries are still being rendered:
[image]
I then opened up spectacle and its entry was not rendered.

Here's what window are opened/minimized when I click on each (mapping is what is rendered->what happens):
firefox->firefox
telegram->remmina
remmina->"arizona" remmina session
thunderbird->spectacle

Also, the clock is frozen. The icons in the system tray still respond when I click on them (network, audio, time, etc) though.

The only way I've found to recover from this is to completely restart the plasma session. It's seriously affecting the usability.

Sorry if my description of the problem wasn't clear, it's hard to articulate fully. Let me know if there is any additional information I could provide to help figure this out.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
The following this lets me at least recover from the bug without needing to log out. I still would like to get to the bottom of why this is happening. https://askubuntu.com/a/481738/1079075. Basically they just do:

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell
kstart5 plasmashell
```

Another update:

After doing the above, I noticed my remmina window wasn't rendering correctly. I'm not sure if this is an issue with KDE or remmina, but I'm adding it here nonetheless. Clicks on the black border seem to go to the desktop behind it, not to remmina.
[image: Showing the weird black border around Remmina]

Comment: Does this `sudo apt remove libqt5quick5-gles` help?