# How to apply changes in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` without closing my session?

Tags: fonts

I am investigating a font configuration problem and I would like to test changes I make in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` and `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` without closing my session.

Is it possible ? Apparently running fc-cache is not enough.

I run Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: How about this https://askubuntu.com/q/481329/26246

Comment: thanks @user.dz but it doesn't do the trick. fontconfig is not updated by restarting plasmashell

Comment: Thanks @xiota I initially tried `sudo fc-cache -f` `-r` doesn't work either. Yes I closed and reopened my program (Firefox). By the way, changes in files stored in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` really do something (which I can test by closing and reopening my session) since  `/etc/fonts/conf.d` contains links to files from  `/etc/fonts/conf.avail`

Comment: @ChrisAga That's strange. Don't know why Firefox isn't picking up the change. What files are you editing and what changes are you making? Is there any reason you're not editing files in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d` ?

Comment: @xiota Everithing is explained here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289600/firefox-hint-issue-when-editing-text-in-roboto-font-how-to-fix-it I was working on this issue.

Comment: Maybe some options are only picked up at login? Do you have this problem with other options, like font families?

Comment: Don't know, I didn't try, but I will and let you know.

Comment: Try something like, `<alias binding="same"><family>Example</family><accept><family>monospace</family></accept></alias>` Should be pretty obvious if the config works.