# Firefox hint issue when editing text in Roboto font. How to fix it?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, fonts

When I edit text on some web pages in Firefox the some of the characters are slightly moving around their original position.
Each time I type a character or move the cursor or hit `delete` or `BS`, the spacing of some character in the text is slightly adjusted. As a result, some characters are kind of "shaking" while I type which bugs me.

Chromium behaves perfectly well on the sames pages.

This issue occurs for instance when I am on my NexCloud pages.

I have Kubuntu 20.04 and Firefox 82.0(64bits) but I noticed this for quite some times now with former versions of Firefox and Kubuntu.
I have the same issue on another computer with a relatively fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04.

I thought I would find some posts about it but apparently nobody was bugged enough to post.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you add screenshots to illustrate?

Comment: It would need to be an animation since the problem is character which are moving ;-) I will try to explain better.

Comment: You could put it in a YouTube video? If you think this is a bug, it might be worth reporting upstream.

Answer (score 2):

After some tests with fontconfig, I found a solution by disabling full hinting on Roboto font.

In `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/56-kubuntu-noto.conf` replace :

```
<edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintfull</const></edit>
```

by :

```
<edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintmedium</const></edit>
```

You must quit your session and reconnect for the change to be effective.
I am not a fontconfig expert. Maybe there is something better to be done, but it works for me.
Since this file comes from the `kubuntu-settings-desktop` package, I assume this is a Kubuntu only issue.

Comment: System config may be overwritten by package updates. Consider putting changes at `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d`.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to fix it for the whole system, not only for my account. Actually I consider adding my own file called just after `56-kubuntu-noto.conf` to address that.

Comment: If you think it fixes a bug, maybe it's worth reporting. Otherwise, I think it's preferable to have in a different file.

Comment: I was actually figuring out how to report a bug to Kubuntu since I never had to until now ;-). There is probably an issue with Firefox too. In fact there is a long history of issues with Firefox and fonts, especially Roboto.

Comment: If the project is on github or gitlab it's pretty easy, just make an account and submit an issue.  But need to make sure submitting to the right project.  Does any other program have problems, or just Firefox?  Also, does the config change cause problems anywhere else?

Comment: Unfortunately I think I have to address the right sub-project in the Ubuntu bug traking system and I cannot identify which one for sure. I probably will try via the Kubuntu forum. I think that only Firefox have this problem and my workaround didn't seem to do any arm.

Comment: The file you're modifying belongs to `fontconfig`.  If only Firefox is affected... you can report there, then see if they redirect you somewhere else.

Comment: I think the shaking issue was fixed a while ago, but the differences in font rendering will persist because Chrome ignores this specific system font configuration. I filed this as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481545 but it's not clear Firefox can do anything sensible about this Ubuntu misconfiguration, without also ending up ignoring some user settings.

Comment: Thanks @gcp ! Slight differences between different browsers are unavoidable and don't matter. The shaking issue seems to be a Firefox bug and the Ubuntu "misconfiguration" wouldn't be ans issue without it. On the other hand this font configuration is not very useful and we can live without it, hence my hack with fontconfig.

Comment: @ChrisAga If you still see the shaking, can you file a bug?

Comment: Actually I have seen other font rendering issues with Noto Sans in the system UI. Maybe it is the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've seen this breaking a lot of pages, not only those using Roboto (the file above fiddles with several fonts, plus configures a lot of fallback stuff), the "nuclear" solution that ultimately fixed all those issues was to remove completely the `56-kubuntu-noto.conf` symlink. To do this and avoid having it restored by future updates:

- remove the symlink: `sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/56-kubuntu-noto.conf`; this doesn't remove the "real" conf file (which lives under `conf.avail`), but fontconfig no longer considers it; this fixes the issue;
- then, make sure the link is no longer created by updates; under `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d`, create a file (I named it `ignore-kubuntu-hinting`) containing:

  ```
  # Ignore defective kubuntu fontconfig directives
  path-exclude=/etc/fonts/conf.d/56-kubuntu-noto.conf
  ```

---

Incidentally, some extra references about this problem, to keep this all cross-linked:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1645681
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481545
- https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/77528-Firefox-hint-issue-when-editing-text-in-Roboto-font-Had-to-fix-56-kubuntu-noto-conf
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/+bug/1872492/

Comment: You're right. It's kind of "nuclear". Thanks for the alternative solution and the extra references.