# KDE Plasma 5.27.8 Taskbar Freeze

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5, kde5

I am running into a problem where my KDE Plasma taskbar (example pictured below) freezes randomly every so often.

[image: KDE Plasma 5.27.8 taskbar]

The only way to unfreeze the taskbar (and get it to render in a current state) was from a solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out) which inspired me to write the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh 
killall plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell 
(kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell) & >/dev/null &
```

It's nice that I have found a way to manually get out of the frozen state, but I am trying to find a solution that doesn't entail me having to stop what I am doing to run a script because of a bug.  All of this is to ask:

1. Is there a way to trigger this script when the taskbar gets into a frozen state? If not...
2. Is there already a fix for this somewhere?

I am running Kubuntu 23.10, Plasma 5.27.8

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, sounds a lot like https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469016

That issue is already fixed but the fix will only come out in plasma 6.0

You can mitigate it by disabling previews (right click icons-only task manager -> configure icons-only task manager -> appearance -> general and disable show small window previews when hovering over tasks)