# SSH remote command execute stays without disconnect when finished execute?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, scripts

I am trying to build a script/command that will restart our Asterisk/Elastix service on our PBX.  The script is basically using simple command with auto log-in public key that run from Ubuntu 14.04LTS:

The command script is:

```
ssh user@iphost 'service asterisk restart'
```

But after the command finished and service restarted, the ssh stays and only after <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> its breaks out.

My question, is how can I terminate the session after the command completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try redirecting stdin, stdout, and stderr to /dev/null.   For an explanation, see https://serverfault.com/questions/36419/using-ssh-to-remotely-start-a-process.

Answer (score 1):

using option **`-t`** (terminal) in ssh command solves the problem too (better than redirecting stdout if command output is something usefull that we want to see):

```
ssh -t remoteip command
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "here document"

```
ssh user@iphos << endexe
   service asterisk restart
   exit
endexe
```

That should work.

Comment: Hi i had "TERM environment variable not set" thanks any idea

Answer (score 0):

You could just background it as soon as it runs:

```
ssh user@iphost 'service asterisk restart &'
```

I've got a similar issue with an `xinit`-based upstart service that hogs the stage and needs manually exiting (doesn't harm the Upstart job), but yeah, wang a `&` on the end and that should force it into the background.

If that gives you gyp, there are [a number of other options](https://askubuntu.com/a/106359/449) like:

```
ssh user@iphost 'setsid service asterisk restart'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following commands instead:

- Restarts the service and then exits:

  ```
  ssh user@iphost 'service asterisk restart; exit'
  ```
- Restarts the service and then exits on success:

  ```
  ssh root@iphost 'service asterisk restart && exit'
  ```

Comment: didn't worked :-(

Comment: Are you sure? The first one should always work. Can you post the output of the command?