# How to run multiple commands in parallel and see output from both?

Tags: command-line

Specifically, I want to run

```
lsyncd lsyncd.lua
```

And

```
webpack --progress --color -w
```

Which are both long-running processes. I want to see the output from both, interlaced in my terminal. It doesn't matter if the results are a bit jumbled, I just like to see that they're doing what they're supposed to.

Also, I want it to kill both processes when I press `Ctrl+C`.

---

I'm trying

```
parallel ::: 'lsyncd lsyncd.lua' 'webpack --progress --color -w'
```

which seems to be working, but I can't see any output even though when I run those commands individually, they output something.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Running programs in the background from terminal](/q/710609); you may also want to look into [Bash's job control](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Your first link links back here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Also, if you're talking about [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/106351/3847) that's the opposite of what I want to do. Pressing Ctrl+C or closing the terminal *should* kill the jobs. I *don't* want to background them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `parallel` (in the `moreutils` package):

```
parallel -j 2 -- 'lsyncd lsyncd.lua' 'webpack --progress --color -w'
```

Since the `parallel` process runs in the foreground, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will terminate all the processes running on top of it at once.

- `-j`: Use to limit the number of jobs that are run at the same time;
- `--`: separates the options from the commands.

```
% parallel -j 2 -- 'while true; do echo foo; sleep 1; done' 'while true; do echo bar; sleep 1; done'
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
^C
%
```

Comment: Aha. That `parallel` seems to be different from than the `parallel` package (GNU?). This one seems to work! The other one just kept saying "parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.".

Answer (score 8):

GNU Parallel defaults to postponing output until the job is finished. You can instead ask it to print output as soon there is a full line.

```
parallel  --lb ::: 'lsyncd lsyncd.lua' 'webpack --progress --color -w'
```

It avoids half-line mixing of the output:

```
parallel -j0 --lb 'echo {};echo -n {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4
```

Spend 20 minutes reading chapter 1+2 of GNU Parallel 2018 ([online](https://zenodo.org/record/1146014), [printed](http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html)). Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Will these prepend lines of output with labels allowing you to distinguish output lines from the two commands? If not, is there an option to do so? And will it preserve colors?

Comment: @Anomaly `--tag/--tagstring/--ctag/--ctagstring` will prepend the lines of each job. Colors is really the job of the program: `parallel --tag ls --color ::: /bin /usr`

Answer (score 2):

`&` to the rescue. It launches the two processes in parallel.

`lsyncd lsyncd.lua & webpack --progress --color -w`

This will do the trick.

Didn't read the `kill` part. A ctrl+C here would only terminate the second one. The process preceding the `&` runs in the background although it outputs on the `stdout`.

The shortest way to terminate both processes is:
1. Type Ctrl+C once. It kills the foreground process.
2. Type `fg` and type Ctrl+C again. It brings the background process to foreground and kills it too.

HTH!

Comment: Derp. So simple. That looks to be doing exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: True. But you cannot stop the first process with Ctrl-C unless you bring it to the foreground.

Comment: @nobody actually you can stop the second one because it's running in foreground. Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh poop. I want them both to die. Need to keep this simple so it's easy to start and stop for the linux noob.

Comment: @mpen can't think of an easy way to kill the process in background. Either use the `jobs` thing in the other answer or run `ps -a` in the shell, that will tell the pid that you can `kill` manually.

Comment: What if I wrap that in parentheses? Like `(lsyncd lsyncd.lua & webpack --progress --color -w)`. Won't that put the whole thing into a "subshell" and then won't Ctrl+C kill the whole subshell, killing both processes?

Comment: @mpen updated the answer with the easiest way. Accept the answer in case you like it.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not an acceptable solution for me. I'm certain there's a way to do this, even if requires an external script.

Comment: @mpen no need to be sorry. Askubuntu just isn't the right place if you're looking for a script. Go to stackoverflow and use the tags `bash` or `shell`. Who knows even I may answer it there... Good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*Using GNU `parallel`*

**1. Output ordered by finishing time of each command**

You could group your parallel executed commands by using `parallel` (install it with `sudo apt install gnu_parallel`) with the argument `--group`. This ensures, that the output of each command waits till the command has finished (avoids mixed output).

Example:

```
parallel --group 'echo -n {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4
```

Output:

```
11
22
33
44
```

From the manual ([`man parallel`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/parallel.1.html)):

```
--group: Group output. Output from each job is grouped together and is 
only printed when the command is finished.
```

**2. Output ordered by the order of input parameters**

Another option is to control the output by the  order of input parameters by using the `-k` argument.

Example:

```
parallel -k 'echo -n {};sleep {};echo {}' ::: 1 3 2 4
```

Output:

```
11
33
22
44
```

From the manual (`man parallel`):

```
--keep-order, -k: Keep sequence of output same as the order of input. 
Normally the output of a job will be printed as soon as the job completes.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have more options. Run the first command and press Ctrl-Z. This puts the command to wait in the background. Now type `bg` and it will run in background. Now run the second command and press Ctrl-Z again. Type `bg` again and both programs will run in background.

Now you can type `jobs` and it will print which commands are running in background. Type `fg <job number>` to put program in foreground again. If you omit the job number it will put the last job in the foreground. When the job is in foreground you can stop it with Ctrl-C. I don't know how you would stop both with one Ctrl-C.

You can also add `&` at the end which puts it running in the background immediately without Ctrl-Z and `bg`. You can still bring it in foreground with `fg`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a light-weight way of doing it without installing anyting.

**Step 1**: Create a script file `runner.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
lsyncd lsyncd.lua &
P1=$!
webpack --progress --color -w &
P2=$!
wait $P1 $P2
```

**Step 2**: Make it executable

```
chmod +x runner.sh
```

**Step 3**: Run it

```
./runner.sh
```

It works like cream

**Explanation**:

1. `some_command &` means run some_command and put it in background
2. `lsyncd lsyncd.lua &` means run `lsyncd lsyncd.lua` and put this process in background.

**Note**: this works with **Debian** based Linux distros like Ubuntu