# close the terminal without terminating the process

Tags: command-line

I started an installation process from a terminal and have two questions about this:

1. How can I close the terminal without terminating the installation process? and how can I restore it again?
2. How can I figure that this terminal has finished processing from another terminal so that I can do other processes based on the result of the first terminal?

Comment: For 1, see http://askubuntu.com/q/106351/158442. There's no easy way to restore if you haven't used `screen` or `tmux` *before* starting the process. 2. Check whether the process is still running using `pgrep`, `top` or some other process monitoring tool.

Comment: A similar question with various good answers and lots of votes can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4004/163108

Answer (score 7):

For 1. you need to send your running process to the background and remove the associated job from current shell.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and type `bg` to send the installation process to the backgroud
- then type `disown`.

[image]

You can now close the terminal, the process will still be alive. You can open another terminal and check its process id with `ps -aef`

[image]

In my case the process id is `14426`. Unfortunately there's no easy way to reattach it to another terminal (See [How to attach terminal to detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process)) unless you used something based on `screen`.

For 2. You can use the following command:

```
while kill -0 14426 >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 5 ; done ; echo "ok"
```

It will print `ok` when the process is over from an other terminal. You can of course change this `echo` command with something more complex.

Source: [BASH: launch background process and check when it ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/bash-launch-background-process-and-check-when-it-ends)