# Why do some applications via the terminal detach automatically and some don't?

Tags: command-line

This is quite an interesting thing I noticed, for instance:

- I use [Atom Editor](https://atom.io) and I call it via my Terminal using:

  ```
  $ atom
  ```

  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which triggers the Editor and also make the terminal cursor point to the new line; making it (Terminal) free for further command line utilities.
- However, when in use **RhythmBox** using `rhythmbox` as terminal command, it tends to work on the foreground (I guess) and keeps the terminal occupied till I close **Rhythmbox** or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I tried this with `texmaker` too and it performs similar thing as **Rhythmbox**. I know that `&` will take the process on the background but is there a logical explanation for some applications as mentioned here?

Any hacks or tips so that I can learn how to tweak things like this?

### Note

I try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on the above mentioned applications and the apps then *gray out* and become unresponsive and I have to force quit on them

#### Environment

- Using **Ubuntu 16.10**
- **Gnome Terminal**
- `echo $SHELL` give `/bin/bash`

Comment: I believe their developers coded this behaviour ( free terminal) into them while others didn't

Comment: George is right. Not a setting. Not tweak-able. Requires a patch the source code.

Comment: You can press Ctrl+Z to "free the terminal", but keep the program open. OR many [other ways](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal/106359#106359)

Comment: It behaves nasty when use CTRL+Z on both rhythmbox and texmaker @M.Becerra
Both apps freeze and do not work. I have to forcefully kill them using their PID

Comment: @user535733 technically, program itself isn't tweakable unless you modify the source code, but there are Linux tools to detach a program from controlling terminal. See my answer

Comment: use Ctrl+Z and then the command bg. Ctrl+Z pauses the program,that is therefore unresponsive, bg sends the program to the background and it is responsive again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, such behavior is specific to each application. Applications written in C programming language, for example, can employ `setsid` call to [disconnect from controlling terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120623/3701431), although they require call to `fork()` [syscall first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613104/3701431). Python, also has `os.setsid()` and `os.fork()` functions; although it is possible to simply use `os.fork()` to [create a child process and kill the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5975124/3701431).

Another very frequent technique that software authors use is launching applications via wrapper script, and calling a new process via `nohup`. That's exactly what `atom` does:

```
$ file $(which atom)
/usr/bin/atom: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
$ grep 'nohup' $(which atom)                                                            
    nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
      cat "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out"
```

You can do so as well. For instance,  the way I tend to launch programs and detach them from terminal is via a function, that launches desired program with `nohup` already appended to the command:

```
runstuff() {
    nohup "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 & 
}
```

Once you define that in your `.bashrc` , you can launch firefox like so :

```
runstuff firefox
```

Another way, is via `setsid` command (which is named same as the C system call, but is actually a standalone binary):

```
setsid firefox
```

Comment: Definitely a thorough answer with a concise understanding. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, yeah nice, nice. But my vote is for the avatar.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ubuntu with X environemnt you can push Ctrl + F2 and then put the command you need (i.e. `rythmbox`). It won't have separate terminal where you can push ctrl+C.

You can also try to run `nohup rythmbox &`. It should run your player in backgroud and make it terminal-close-proof.