# How can I record sound in background

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I would like to run a command to be executed in background monitoring the output to the speaker and record what's played.

I used the following command:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 - test.ogg silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

It works, but it is running in forground listening to the device... I tried use `tmux` but it didn't record the sound.... any solution?

I prefer a command line as a startup service to listen to the speaker output as long as it's not stopped, however later I found `pulseaudio` as a required service isn't run as a wide-system service and making it wide-system causes some problems in sound system....

Now this question isn't my priority but if one knows a solution can offer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running programs in the background from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal)

Comment: @user3140225 No, my question isn't about running a program in background, but a solution for running recording sounds in backgroun, I myself found some solutions and will post it later

Comment: Can you clarify that you are looking to record audio playing through your speakers, for instance a music clip? Does it have to be command line? I believe Audacity can record audio going to the speakers, but it is a GUI.

Comment: @Raffles I prefered a command line as a startup service to listen to the speaker output as long as it's not stopped, however later I found `pulseaudio` isn't run as a wide-system and making it wide causes some problems in sounds, etc.