# Clear the terminal without stopping the program

Tags: command-line, konsole

Is it possible to clear a terminal but without having to stop the current running program

Comment: Probably yes. However, please elaborate on the situation. Which program is running? Is it displaying output? You can put a process to the background by pressing `Ctrl + Z`, and then resume it with the command `fg` - does this match your usecase?

Comment: Yes. thanks @ArturMeinild this is what i am looking for

Comment: @ArturMeinild Would you mind posting that as an answer as it should work for the OP? I’d upvote it if you did - thanks!

Comment: It's a duplicate - the answer is in the above thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/603583/1066942).