# Ubuntu 14.04 window problem after waking up from suspend

Tags: 14.04, compiz, panel

I have a new HP Z BOOK 15 and I terminated windows and installed Ubuntu 14.04. All are working fine except that at certain times when I suspend the laptop and log back in again, the window panels get blank.

[image]

Here is the image of how it looks after logging back in after a suspend.

It happens all the time BUT only after two or three suspends.

I know that this is a question that cannot have a direct answer (or maybe it does!!) as I don't have any details that I can provide to explain further than the image itself.

Comment: Does restarting compiz or unity help? It should not close your windows, but might move them to a different workspace.
You can achieve this by running `compiz --replace` or `unity --replace` in a terminal.
(see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31167/how-can-i-restart-compiz-from-tty-related-how-can-i-set-up-a-fallback-wm#31171)

Comment: I go though your lappy **HP Z BOOK 15** details. The problem relates to your Graphics Drivers. your lappy supports `Intel HD Graphics 4600` `NVIDIA Quadro K610M` `NVIDIA Quadro K2100M` graphics drivers. Find out and install one by one from three of them. Try it.

Comment: This problem [looks similar to this.][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/471181/blank-screen-after-suspend-hibernate-on-14-04

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it happens after 2 or 3 suspends.  Short of running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

before and after a bad suspend, it will be difficult to tell.

I believe you can, however, run

```
compiz --replace
```

from a terminal to fix your window issues (it's worked for me in the past, sometimes waking up from suspend I won't have window borders to click/close/minimize).

Try to get a pre and post log so we can look at that and figure out what's going wrong when suspending that causes this.

Answer (score 1):

I also get occasional glitches like this after suspend, which can usually be resolved by switching to console (CTRL-ALT-F1) and then back to the desktop (ALT-F7).

Comment: This would be considered a work-around rather than a resolution/answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I found the solution here.

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS black screen after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779595/ubuntu-16-04-lts-black-screen-after-login)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks [similar to this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471181/blank-screen-after-suspend-hibernate-on-14-04). It looks like the solution is in there, open all the comments. Both the suspend and hibernate may have the same root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your compiz configurations by entering the following into terminal:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to see an error in the display/driver message log that will tell you what is causing this. To do this, open up a new terminal window and run the following command to view logs in a paging view:

`dmesg | more`

To go to the next page of logs, simply press spacebar.