# Blank screen after suspend/hibernate on 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, suspend, hibernate

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.
Everything works great except after hibernate/suspend I am getting a black screen.
I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to restart and the screen comes back fine.

I am using the open-source `X.org X-server` drivers.

My laptop is hp pavilion g6, APU A8-3520M with Radeon HD 6620G

What can I do to make screen come back after suspend/hibernation?
I've checked some old thread from 2010 where people add a little piece of code to somewhere in the system to force the screen come back or something.

Comment: Seems to be this Bug [Ubuntu 14.04 blank screen after wakeup from sleep](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1283938) Did you try with installed "Addidtional Driver" for your GPU?

Comment: Well, by "additional driver" do you mean the proprietary one downloaded from AMD website?
The problem with them is that, if I install them, and open Scilab Advanced CLI, I will be getting a warning like this:
"Libegl warning: DRI2 failed to authenticate"

But this thread you just posted, does not present any solution?
Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry I got into ubuntu a month ago, is this a terminal command or what?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Terminal command was recognized but there was no reaction or any error.
But it absolutely didn't do anything and suspending/hibernating is still the same as ever.
Does this have a real solution?

Comment: Well, as I said installing the driver from the AMD website solves the problem but it will give the warning I mentioned above for Scilab.
I am trying to get hibernate/suspend working on x.org x.server open source drivers?

What should I do in this case?

I appreciate your insight ;)

Comment: Ok if you want you can post some logs from the `/var/log/` -> pm-suspend, syslog and after a blank screen go to terminal then `dmesg > $HOME/dmseg1.log` (copy all to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and link it to your question) perhaps someone find something useful.

Comment: Well here is the pm-suspend.log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506498/

But I still think that suspending works it is the screen that doesn't turn on.

Comment: Yes you are right syslog, dmesg and xorg.log would be more interesting.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506575/
This is dmesg ~~~~~

And this one is xorg http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506580/

Comment: I'm unable to post syslog because it is 472 pages,

Comment: Check if this works for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395

Comment: I will do this and report back :)
Looks promising, thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this did not work, the only thing it changed was the second after I hit suspend it switches to Virtual Console and would supposedly go back after resume but the problem is it just damn can't...
Is there an actual "piece of code" that can make the screen turn on? 
To my knowledge this piece just triggered switching to VC that's it.

Thanks again to every one of you :)

Comment: I think it is relate to some kernel bug, I'm on 14.04 , I have Sandy Bridge intel and I'm experiencing this issue from last 3/4 weeks

Answer (score 7):

Killing the process `light-locker` (discovered by using `xwininfo`) helped us temporarily, then uninstalling `light-locker` with `dpkg --purge light-locker light-locker-settings` fixed it more permanently.

We are using Gnome 3, so this might not be a solution for everybody.

(In general, there's probably a process displaying a black screen that you need to kill; try to find it!)

Comment: Thank you so much!! You were a lifesaver. I read through at least 30 bugreports and couldn't find a problem. I was using the open-source `radeon` driver. But after removing `light-locker`, everything worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 3):

Which kernel are you using? Check this with `uname -r`. I am not a fan of the AMD proprietary drivers on Linux. I find lots of issues with them. I prefer running the open source drivers and newer kernels have many new fixes and features for AMD graphics. You can take the OPEN SOURCE ROUTE, or the PROPRIETARY ROUTE.

**OPEN SOURCE ROUTE**

If you are using 3.13, then try the newer 3.16 kernel

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

or try the entire Utopic [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) which is better...

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

If you are already running 3.16, then try removing the Utopic LTS Enablement Stack

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

If none of this helps, you can try the newest stable kernel. This is a bit more tricky, and could cause some issues, but I have been running the linux 4.0 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 for a while now with no issues.

```
mkdir linux4-0-4
cd linux4-0-4
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.4-wily/linux-headers-4.0.4-040004-generic_4.0.4-040004.201505171336_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.4-wily/linux-image-4.0.4-040004-generic_4.0.4-040004.201505171336_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.4-wily/linux-headers-4.0.4-040004_4.0.4-040004.201505171336_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.0*.deb linux-image-4.0*.deb
```

After installing or removing any kernels, you will need to reboot in order to test them.

**PROPRIETARY ROUTE**

You can [install the AMD proprietary Catalyst driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) fairly easily in Ubuntu 14.04. Simply run

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

If you are using multiple AMD graphics cards or AMD dual graphics (i.e.: notebook users), use:

```
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
```

After installing or removing Catalyst, you will need to reboot in order to test.

Comment: Saved my life...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem that Ubuntu could not load after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. After running `startx` there was just a black screen. I fix it by going to recovery mode and just picking **Repair broken packages and check all file systems**, but I think only the first option will work.

Comment: Can you check if you can recover from hibernating on open-source graphics drivers?
I am fairly certain that they are terribly faulty.
-
-
-
Also, I would appreciate a little more details about the approach you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure it is a kernel bug (I have the same issue with Intel, and it started only 3-4 weeks ago).

Try to install a different (old) kernel and boot with it. Right now in the repository I can see this is the oldest kernel version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Comment: Same here on a **Lenovo Latitude T400**. It works after I loaded a **former kernel** at startup. (Press left `Shift` key while booting to activate *Grub*.)

Comment: what you mean with `former kernel` ... anyway on my laptop looks working with last updates ( I'm running 14.10 )

Comment: You can boot your machine with an earlier kernel by pressing the left `Shift` key at start-up time. This launches *Grub* where you can select the *former kernel*. Note that I am still running 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Did you turn off the power of the Radeon graphical device? Because I did it and what you describe here was what I experienced. I canceled the VGA power turning off and the standby exit works again for me.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I opened a [meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15942/271) about one of your edits. I'm tagging you because it's correct to inform you about this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the very same problem on Xubuntu 14.10 my Lenovo Yoga.

I've unchecked the 'Configure new displays when connected' checkbox at display settings dialog.

Give it a try - I hope it helps.

Comment: @peter-mortensen, yes.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many different suggestions, I finally gave up on 14.04 and installed 15.04 and now the problem is gone.

I have installed 15.04 on Lenovo Yoga 2 pro.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with NVidia card.  Light Locker did not fix it.  Solution:  Make sure to switch to using NVidia screen drivers by first **making sure you have a live Internet connection**, then

```
System Tools->Software Updater ->  (Settings) button
[Additional Drivers]  tab

NVidia Corporation:  Unknown          select radio button:
  (*) Using NVIDIA binary driver--version etc. (tested)
  ( ) Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau
(Apply Changes) button, it takes a while to download & install
**restart your computer**
```

check your install with System Tools->NVIDIA X Server Settings, should be there and come up with the green penguin splash on the tool.

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Dell Inspiron 3558 with nvidia graphics (GK208M (GeForce 920M) with driver 340.102) with Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit intel i5).

Earlier I did a software update and kernel version was:

```
linux-image-3.13.0-144-generic 3.13.0-144.193 amd64
Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Whenever I suspended (closed the laptop lid), it never started, although I could hear the fan start. I saw some posts on increasing hibernate swap memory, but I didn't think that could be the issue because earlier when I purchased the laptop it was working and even after I custom increased my RAM. I installed Ubuntu afresh as well.

It was just after a particular kernel update that it was gone.

So, I updated `linux-generic` (currently 3.13.0-160-generic), and I tested it with heavy load software and suspension. It works fine now :)

Comment: You updated the kernel, so in your case it was a bug in the kernel. This is different from OP's device, so it's not the same problem.

Comment: X-server settings also disoriented this once when I update them to with new drivers for nvida(any version > 360 doesn't work). Lightdm problem still occurs for me. Not all kernel updated resolved my problem, but the version i mentioned did, also posted this to ubuntu resolution center. Hope to help.