# Black Screen after login (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: gnome, login, xorg, gdm

**Problem**: After typing in my credentials I am greeted by a black screen with a cursor. My desktop environment does not load. How can I resolve this issue and get my desktop environment to load?

**System**: Ubuntu 20.04; Gnome 3.36.4; GDM; XOrg; No Nvidia Graphics.

**Details**: Right before this happened I enabled fractional scaling and set it to 125%. Then I rebooted which is when the problem occurred for the first time. I can log in to ubuntu on wayland. So I suspect that the problem is with XOrg.

**What I've tried**

- Fixing potentially unsuccessful update following the first answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779595/ubuntu-16-04-lts-black-screen-after-login) question.
- Checked startup jobs following this [blog entry](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-black-screen-after-login-18-04/).
- Reinstalled gdm3 following the system76 [guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it. The problem was fractional scaling.

**Solution**: I logged into a wayland session and set fractional scaling back to 100%.

**Procedure**: Logged into a wayland session. Went to Settings > Displays > Set the fractional scaling back to 100% and disabled fractional scaling. Then I did a reboot and tried logging into an XOrg session which worked again.

Comment: life saver.. tho I had not enabled fractional scaling.. the wayland session worked.. not sure why the regular sessions stopped??