# Screen becomes pixellated after waking from hibernation

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Starting today, every time my computer wakes up from hibernation I get a screen that looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what's going on? I tried some of the fixes mentioned here: [Ubuntu 14.04 window problem after waking up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466385/ubuntu-14-04-window-problem-after-waking-up-from-suspend), [Blank screen after suspend/hibernate on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471181/blank-screen-after-suspend-hibernate-on-14-04)

I also tried reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers, which did not work either. I'm on Ubunt 16.10 on a HP m7 notebook with NVIDIA GeForce 840M. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Screenshot of "Additional Drivers" GUI.
[image]

Comment: It's a bug reported for some newer Nvidia drivers versions. It shouldn't happen if you use the drivers available at the official repositories.

Comment: To reinstall the drivers, I just did "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current". That should work, right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, unless you have legacy hardware."Current" is arguably misleading because it suggests the current version when in reality it installs the "current long term support" driver for legacy hardware as in the last driver you'll ever ever have for that old card. Not the case here.

Comment: I see. How should I revert the driver then?

Comment: The "additional drivers" tool (either search it in the dash or find it as a tab in Settings > Software & Updates) should be enough. Simply select the recommended driver version. apply and reboot when done. If not, we can try other solutions. Meanwhile please update your question (edit) and post the exact Nvidia card model you have.

Comment: Hmm, it's telling me that I'm using the recommended driver already.

Comment: You are indeed (but you should also install the CPU microcode although not related). The bug has been reported with the 375 version and newer. 370 or 367 apparently don't produce this effect.

Comment: Ah ok, switching back to 340 solved the problem. Thanks for your help!