# Killed compiz task with top, then system exploded

Tags: boot, compiz

I was reading around [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869500/why-my-ubuntu-16-04-lts-suddenly-become-very-slow) about how to fix a slow system. Like he says, for me everything after load average was like 5-7. So I tried using top to kill some of the biggest CPU hogs. One was Compiz. I killed Compiz which I understand now was stupid. I forget what happened exactly but I'm pretty sure everything went black. I tried rebooting, I can get to the login screen but when I log in I just go to a black screen, occasionally one icon might pop up, or the WiFi box will show but that's it. I tried getting into grub and was able to get to the command line a couple times. But now I can't even get to GRUB. I'm not sure what I would do there anyway. I also tried turning off secure boot. What should I do? I don't want to erase my stuff but I'm about to just re install Ubuntu.

**Update:**
I am able to get to the console with ctr alt f1, I ran top and didn't see top, I ran pgrep compiz and got nothing. If I switch back using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I can see my mouse but nothing else. Checked out this post [How can I restart Compiz from a TTY? (& Related, how can I set up a fallback WM?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31167/how-can-i-restart-compiz-from-a-tty-related-how-can-i-set-up-a-fallback-wm)

But when I run `DISPLAY=:0` Unity  it says:

```
compiz (core) - Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - starting plugin
compiz (core) - loading plugin: opnegl
compiz (core) - starting plugin: opengl

dconf - warning **: failed to commit changes to dconf: could not connect: connection refused.
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/31171/29073 should fix it: `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace `.

Comment: Ran that command but it is not returning, Now I can see a single file that was on my desktop but nothing else, everything else is black.

Comment: Did you try anything else from the link I gave?

Comment: Yea! I tried a bunch of things, I think it was the --replace unity that finally fixed it.